# How do you access menu items in webdriverio (Spectron)?

Tags: e2e-testing, webdriver-io, spectron

I am building a set of e2e tests with Spectron and webdriverio for an Electron App. I would like to access the browser's menu bar. Even just being able to have Spectron click on 'File' and then 'New File' would be great.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it looks like this is currently [unsupported](https://github.com/electron/spectron/issues/21):

> ... the require('electron').remote.Menu.getApplicationMenu() API does not serialize to JSON so it can't currently be fetched via Spectron.

Comment: It should be noted that there is also a work around mentioned in that link.